# How do I convert a cli::array to a native array from native code?

Tags: .net, c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I'm writing a native wrapper around a managed component written in C++\CLI.

I have the following function in managed code:

```
array<Byte>^ Class::Function();
```

I want to expose this function from a native C++ class with the following signature:

```
shared_array<unsigned char> Class::Function();
```

I've gotten as far as calling the managed function from native code, but I'm not sure how to safely copy the managed array into an unmanaged one.

```
gcroot<cli::array<System::Byte>^> managedArray = _managedObject->Function();
```

Comment: How do you expect to return a non-copyable, non-movable object from a function?

Comment: That is an excellent point - I suppose I don't actually :S. Should be a shared_array.

Comment: I assume `shared_array` is from boost, am I right?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Correct. For the purposes of this question though it could just as easily be `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Note that if you're using VC++ 2010 (or the VC11 preview), `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` would be the ideally-efficient return type.

Comment: @ildjarn - Interesting, unique_ptr will correctly call `delete []`. I didn't know that.

Comment: `unique_ptr<T>` will call `delete`, but `unique_ptr<T[]>` will call `delete[]`. :-]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two usual approaches:

1. Perform the marshaling with native code, which requires use of [`pin_ptr<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/pin-ptr-cpp-cli):

   ```
    boost::shared_array<unsigned char> convert(array<unsigned char>^ arr)
    {
        boost::shared_array<unsigned char> dest(new unsigned char[arr->Length]);
        pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinned = &arr[0];
        unsigned char* src = pinned;
        std::copy(src, src + arr->Length, dest.get());
        return dest;
    }
   ```
2. Perform the marshaling with managed code, which requires use of the [Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netframework-4.8) class:

   ```
    boost::shared_array<unsigned char> convert(array<unsigned char>^ arr)
    {
        using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

        boost::shared_array<unsigned char> dest(new unsigned char[arr->Length]);
        Marshal::Copy(arr, 0, IntPtr(dest.get()), arr->Length);
        return dest;
    }
   ```

Generally I would prefer the latter approach, as the former can hinder the GC's effectiveness if the array is large.

Comment: I think I will take the latter approach on second thought. Since I have ownership of the managed code, I can simply add an internal function to return the data as a shared_array.

Comment: @ildjarn: Since `std::copy` is a template, wouldn't it work properly with an `interior_ptr`?

Comment: @Ben : I don't believe so, as there's no specialization of `std::iterator_traits<>` for `interior_ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`pin_ptr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18132394.aspx), it lets you pass address of a managed class to an unmanaged function.