# How to access IEnumerable<byte> in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have an interface defined in C# like this:

```
public interface ISender
{
    ReponseType SendData(PacketType packet);
}
```

Where the `PacketType` looks like this (C#) again:

```
public struct PacketType
{
    public IEnumerable<byte> PartOne;
    public IEnumerable<byte> PartTwo;
}
```

I'd like to write one implementation of this interface in C++ (since one protocol implementation is provided in a C++ lib, and jumping between managed and unmanaged code is rather easy in C++).  I've created a `ref class` and implemented enough of the required method to compile, link, and debug:

```
ResponseType MySender::SendData(PacketType packet)
{
    return ResponseType::Failure;
}
```

Now I'm stuck on getting converting the `IEnumerable`s into `uint8_t *`, and on getting their lengths.  According to IntelliSense they have the type `System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<unsigned char> ^`, and they have no public methods at all attached to them.

This seems like something that ought to be obvious, so I feel I must have missed something obvious.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> does have methods, see Reflector. To get the length you need to call Enumerable.Count (which can be O(N)).

Comment: Unless you are working in VS 2005, this would be C++/CLI and should be tagged that instead of C++.

Comment: And if you are using Visual Studio 2010, C++/CLI intellisense just doesn't work.

Comment: BTW: Are you sure you want to have anything to do with [tag:managed-c++]?

Comment: I'm in VS2013, so I suppose it's C++/CLI then, but who can be bothered keeping up with the latest marketing from MS? ;)

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to first convert IEnumerable to a managed array, then convert the managed array to a native one.

As ToArray is an extension method, in C++/CLI, you can call it as a static function:

```
array<unsigned char>^ a = Enumerable::ToArray<unsigned char>(PartOne);
```

As how to copy data from managed array to native array, you can find how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759645/how-do-i-convert-a-cliarray-to-a-native-array-from-native-code).

Comment: Generally MSDN is rather easy to use (especially via Google ;), usually it's enough to just serch for "MSDN <function name>".  Not so with C++/CLI though.  Direct links into MSDN areas covering C++/CLI would be useful, e.g. is there any documentation of `Enumerable::ToArray`?  Or am I supposed to always translate the C# docs into C++?

Comment: @Magnus There is documentation for C++/CLI here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx. But it only covers basics. Compare to C#, the documentation for C++/CLI is very poor.

Comment: This is making me feel rather silly, but how do I even get the Linq stuff into C++/CLI?  `using namespace System::Linq;` tells me that `System` has no namespace `Linq`.

Comment: I managed to find that out myself in the end: `#using <System.Core.dll>`, `#using <System.Linq.dll>`, and then `using System::Linq;`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why Intellisense isn't working but you should have *some* public methods available (`GetEnumerator` and methods inherited from `object`).  You won't see extension methods but you should be able to call them as static methods from the `Enumerable` class:

```
int partOneCount = Enumerable::Count(packet -> PartOne);
int partTwoCount = Enumerable::Count(packet -> PartTwo);
```

(I may have the C++ syntax slightly off since I don't use it much but you should get the idea - anyone is free to correct the syntax)